How to change the color of lines in a sunburst chart?
I'm working on a sunburst plot looking at wins, losses, and ties in chess. If the player won, it shows up green, tie, yellow, and lost red.
Is there any way to change the lines between each section to be black instead of white?
Here is my code:
fig = go.Figure(
            go.Sunburst(
                ids=ids,
                labels=labels,
                parents=parents,
                values=values,
                marker = dict(
                        colors = colors,
                        colorscale = 'RdYlGn_r',
                        colorbar = dict(
                                    thickness = 20,
                                    title = dict(
                                            text = 'White/Black Winning Percentage',
                                            side = 'right'
                                            )
                                    )
                        ),
                leaf = {
                        'opacity': 1.0
                        },
                branchvalues="total",  # if children exceed parent, graph will crash and not show
                insidetextorientation="horizontal",  # text displays PP
                hovertext=[
                    str(percentage_everything[i])
                    + "% of Parent<br>Game Count: "
                    + str(values[i])
                    + '<br>Opening: '
                    + hovertip_openings[i]
                    + '<br>W/B Winning Percentage: ' # Note: this is wins+1/2draws/wins+losses+draws
                    + str(ratios[i])
                    for i in range(len(percentage_everything))
                ],
                hovertemplate="%{hovertext}<extra></extra>",
            )
        )

Outcome:

I was able to change the colors from grey-scale to Green Yellow Red but don't know how to change the lines
